# Regex to limit string length for strings with new line characters

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

Looks like a simple task - get a regex that tests a string for particular length: 
^.{1,500}$

But if a string has "\r\n" than the above match always fails!

How should the correct regex look like to accept new line characters as part of the string?

I have a `<asp:TextBox TextMode="Multiline">` and use a RegularExpressionValidator to check the length of what user types in.

Thank you,
Andrey

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option when validating input. This treats the input as a single line statement, and parses it as such.

Otherwise you could give the following expression a try:

```
^(.|\s){1,500}$
```

This should work in multiline inputs.

Comment: Can you please replace closing bracket with curly bracket; otherwise it worked, thanks!

Comment: Upvoted but those using this for validation should be wary that technically, this can be bypassed with 500 [ENTER] for example.

Answer (score 0):

Can you strip the line breaks before checking the length of the string? That'd be easy to do when validating server-side. (In .net you could use a custom validator for that)

From a UX perspective, though, I'd implement a client-side 'character counter' as well. There's plenty to be found. jQuery has a few options. Then you can implement the custom validator to only run server-side, and then use the character counter as your client-side validation. Much nicer for the user to see how many characters they have left WHILE they are typing.

Comment: I'm using asp.net's RegularExpressionValidator, it does both client and server side validation using provided regex

Comment: My suggestion is to use the REGEX only server side (turn off client side for that control) as that's really just for validating data going into the DB. Client side, instead of validating it after the fact, I'd suggest a live 'character counter' as it's a much nicer indicator from the user experience perspective. This would really only make sense if you are already using jQuery or something as it'd be easy to add. If not, maybe not worth it just for this one field.

Comment: er, let me rephrase...if the REGEX is still an issue, validate server-side using a custom control. You could just check for string length easily server-side and forget the REGEX. Then use the javascript method of live counting the characters client-side.

Answer (score 0):

The inability to set the RegexOptions is screwing you up here.  Since this is in a RegularExpressionValidator, you could try setting the options in the regular expression itself.

I think this should work:

```
(?s)^.{1,500}$
```

The (?s) part turns on the Singleline option which will allow the dot to match every character including line feeds.  For what it's worth, [the article here also lists the other RegexOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx) and the notation needed to set them as an inline statement.

Comment: This expression breaks in client side validation - Javascript doesn't understand (?s)

Comment: Ah yes, Javascript validation.  Sorry about that.