# Kafka Connect - json path - regex condition not working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, jsonpath

I have an application where I use a connector to save data to a database.
I want to filter the messages saved by removing the ones that have a certain property very long.
My messages are like this :

```
{
  field_a : value,
  field_b : value,
  field_c : possible very long value
}
```

So, I used in the kafka connector the Confluent Filter like this :

```
transforms: filterSpam
transforms.filterSpam.type: io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value
transforms.filterSpam.filter.condition: $[?(@.field_c =~ /^.{32000,}$/)]
transforms.filterSpam.filter.type: exclude
transforms.filterSpam.missing.or.null.behavior: include
```

For some reason the filter is not working. All messages pass through.

I tried also with the negation :

```
$[?(!(@.field_c =~ /^.{1,32000}$/))]
```

In this case, the very long were filtered out, but also some of the shorter ones were.

I do not understand where the issue is coming from. Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I needed to update my regex knowledge.
The issue was related to the fact that the string field on which I tried to apply the regex sometimes was multiline.
Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1616317) I managed to use a proper validation of the size of this field.
The final solution is :

```
transforms.filterSpam.filter.condition: $[?(@.field_c =~ /(\s)^.{32000,}$/)]
```